# Dynamically Populate Chef Cookbook Attributes

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying to create a recipe which pulls in variables which are defined in a YAML configuration file and then uses their values as recipe attributes.

A couple points:

1. My `config.yml` file resides in the root of my chef directory (that is, outside of my `cookbooks` directory, and on the same level as my `Vagrantfile` which drives the provisioning process.
2. I use a similar approach to populate values into my `Vagrantfile`, which is what gave me the idea for this solution.  I want to maintain a list of user-configurable values which need to be used in both my `Vagrantfile` as well as various recipes inside various cookbooks.

As an example, here are two values from `config.yml`:

```
---
basics:
  vm_ip: 192.168.56.11
  vm_hostname: luma.com
```

I use the following in my `Vagrantfile` to read these values:

```
require 'yaml'
config_file = "config.yml"
settings = YAML.load_file(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) + "/#{config_file}")
```

And I reference them as such elsewhere in the `Vagrantfile` (Syntax abbreviated):

```
machine.vm.network 'private_network', ip: settings['basics']['vm_ip']
machine.vm.hostname = settings['basics']['vm_hostname']
```

This approach works great for the `Vagrantfile`, but of course, that's outside of Chef's purview.

From a Chef perspective, I thought I could perhaps follow a similar approach, since Chef is Ruby-based.  I have a cookbook `base` with an `attributes` folder, and a `default.rb` attributes file.  My initial attempt was to simply duplicate the approach in `default.rb`:

```
require 'yaml'
config_file = "config.yml"
settings = YAML.load_file(File.dirname(File.expand_path("../../../", __FILE__)) + "/#{config_file}")
```

And then reference the `config.yml` values as attributes like so:

```
default['vm']['ip'] = settings['basics']['vm_ip']
default['vm']['hostname'] = settings['basics']['vm_hostname']
```

This fails because, as I've (naively) learned, the `__FILE__` value refers to a path on the node rather than to a file in the local directory, as this attributes file is used during convergence, etc.  Stupid me.

So, my thought now is to dynamically populate the attributes file as part of the `Vagrantfile`, since that's outside of Chef's process.  Before I go through the effort of writing that, I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate chef-based approach I should consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i might be wrong, but it seems you are trying to invent the wheel. let me elaborate...

## vagrant

from vagrant perspective, you should leverage [test-kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen) in conjunection with [`vagrant` driver](https://kitchen.ci/docs/drivers/vagrant/).

once you set it up, take advantage of custom kitchen configuration -- [use general configuration and (user) custom configuration](https://kitchen.ci/docs/reference/configuration/) (each user might have a different custom conifugration, corresponding to the `config.yml` you mentioned`)

note also, that `kitchen.yml` supports [erb](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#class-ERB-label-Recognized+Tags). you can use it to do things dynamically.

## chef

from chef perspective, is a configuration management and you should use it correctly. that is, rather than using an external file (`config.yml`) to feed chef with values, take advantage of [recipe attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html), [json attributes](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#options) or even [data bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html) to store values which will be used during your recipe.

note that attributes can be generated dynamically, you will just have to put some logic for that (same as you did for `config.yml`)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!  Your answer prompted me to re-think my approach a bit and to make better use of attributes and roles to achieve something more in line with Chef best practices.  The chef + vagrant project is part of a larger whole, so test kitchen won't help as much here, but the deeper dive into attributes, roles, and environments has certainly gotten me much closer to my goal.  For any other readers out there, I did write a mapper from my config.yml to Chef's default attributes.  I think Mr.'s advice is well-warranted, so I'll accept the answer.